# What is the best way to write Python notebooks that use Google Cloud Runtimes? (ex. within Google Colab, Google Colab Enterprise)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, runtime, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

At work we have been developing and training various types of machine learning models in Google Colab Pro for a while. We recently started using Google Cloud, and as such, we have access to more powerful and flexible resources to create custom Runtimes, with whatever GPUs and other resources we want.

Now that we can access these resources, what is the best way to access them? Google Colab Enterprise is an option, however it lacks nice to haves like Dark Mode, and all around just seems rough around the edges and feels less like an IDE than regular Colab is.

Is there a way to access the Google Cloud Runtimes from a local IDE like VS Code? Is there a better workflow to write notebooks and have access the the Google Cloud Runtimes?

Comment: We have a FR for Dark Mode and our main dependency now is Google Cloud Console. A difference between Colab and Colab Enterprise UI is that Colab Enterprise web app lives inside Google Cloud Console, hence the dependency for this specific topic. For second topic, I also opened a FR to allow remote connectivity between IDEs and Colab Enterprise Runtimes, as a workaround, you could use User Managed Notebooks or Workbench Instances to establish an SSH tunnel and use IDE. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/ssh-access

Comment: One idea is to use User Managed Notebooks custom container with Colab Container. https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1663594080436375558 to get same environment as Colab and then use SSH tunnel method I mentioned above.

Comment: I've been trying with VSCode JupyterLab extension but requires token which we dont support, will try to see if I can make it work

Comment: I will try https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/notebook-kernels-mixer and get back to you.